# set video output as xvimagesink

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, gstreamer

I have Cheese application. But, it has mentioned to change video output as xvimagesink for

better performance on video recording.

I am using the the back end part of the Cheese source code(Open source) and creating my own

UI.

It works fine for normal image capture and video display rate is fine when streaming from

web camera. When i call recording video method, the video rate is very slow.

So, my query is how can i set video output as xvimagesink.

Regards,
iSight

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While recording video using Cheese, change the resolution size by 352x288 in preference.

Then the issue of slow frame recording will not exist. And enjoy recording video using

Cheese.

Regards,
iSight

Answer (score 0):

Look for the `cheese_webcam_create_video_display_bin`function in `cheese-webcam.c`. It uses `gconfvideosink` by default, which lets you configure which video sink you would like using a Gnome user interface. That or `autovideosink` (picks the video output that gstreamer thinks is best) are probably better than `xvimagesink`.

Comment: I could not notice the file cheese-webcam.c. It is cheese-camera.c. Can you please provide the link, where i could get the sources which you mentioned.

Comment: I was probably looking at an older version of cheese. Search the source code for gconfvideosink.

Comment: It seems in new version, gconfvideosink is not using at all... By the way, how can make the application more efficient while recording video...